# How to link an existing question to a proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

I added a proposal: [**Pharmacy**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101153/pharmacy) as a reaction to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9220/can-we-start-a-pharmacy-qa-site, but it does not show up as a related discussion in [the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101153/pharmacy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commenting doesn't link the discussion to the proposal, adding the proposal link to the post does.

Anyway - in this case, the question doesn't appear to be *about* that specific proposal (but rather a request to add the proposal), so I can't think of a reason you would like to link it.